# Flutter Because easy_localization

Tags: flutter

Note: intl is pinned to version 0.18.1 by flutter_localizations from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.

Because easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety requires intl 0.18.1.
So, because emartstore depends on both intl ^0.17.0 and easy_localization ^3.0.1, version solving failed.
Process finished with exit code

Please Help Me Im new in  flutter

Comment: before I come as being rude to you, you should understand the frustration that many stackoverflow users willing to help bear with such poorly formatted questions. I understand that you are new to SO. so I suggest starting at the basic guidelines as linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). TL;DR, your question is poorly formatted, your title is incomprehensible, you have not included any if at all traces of code. And the context is unknown. The whole question is unanswerable, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

karan bhai, just put these line in pubspec.yaml

```
  intl:
  easy_localization:
```